# Method containing "this" keyword works different when it's called in another method vs when it's assigned to a local variable

Tags: javascript, constructor, this, ecmascript-5

Having the following code, the output is undefined when calling the Play method from my object instance while I was expecting the 'this' keyword to reference the global variable and display "Football" in lack of a PlayGound's scope variable.

```js
var game = "Football";

function Play() {
  console.log(this.game)
}

function PlayGround() {
  this.Play = Play;
}

var obj = new PlayGround();
obj.Play();
```

Now, invoking the Play() at constructor level, without passing it's reference to a local variable the output is "Football".

```js
var game = "Football";

function Play() {
  console.log(this.game)
}

function PlayGround() {
  Play();
}

var obj = new PlayGround();
```

Can someone explain the reason why those two aproaches behave differently?

Comment: It doesn't matter *where* it is called, it matters *how* it is called - `obj.Play()` vs. `Play()`. You also should use strict mode.

Answer (score 3):

The first one outputs `undefined` very simply because `obj` does not have a `game` property. That can be fixed like this:

```js
var game = "Football";

function Play() {
  console.log(this.game)
}

function PlayGround() {
  this.game = game;
  this.Play = Play;
}

var obj = new PlayGround();
obj.Play();
```

The second snippet is bad practice because it relies on mechanics of [non-strict mode simple calls](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#Simple_call) in order to work.

If you change the second snippet to strict mode it will error because `this` in simple calls is `undefined` instead of `window`:

```js
"use strict";

var game = "Football";

function Play() {
  console.log(this.game)
}

function PlayGround() {
  Play();
}

var obj = new PlayGround();
```

If you use `let` or `const` declaration for `game`, the second snippet will output `undefined` because those top-level declarations do not attach to the global scope `window`:

```js
let game = "Football";

function Play() {
  console.log(this.game)
}

function PlayGround() {
  Play();
}

var obj = new PlayGround();
```